# Scp or rsync 90 days older files to remote server (EC2)

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-ec2, scripting, scp

I am trying to get the logs file that are older then 90 days and trying to send them to remote server that is ec2 instance. I am trying this command but it is not working.

```
find /var/log/* -mtime +90 -print0 | rsync --remove-source-files -av -e ssh -i keypair.pem ubuntu@ip:/
```

It gives this error:

```
ubuntu@ip: Permission denied (publickey).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-i is option of ssh, not rsync. You are using -e. Good, but you have to pass to it all of ssh parameters in quotes.
And second thing You have to tell rsync that You are piping something via stdin

`find /var/log/* -mtime +90 -print0 | rsync --remove-source-files -av -e 'ssh -i keypair.pem' --files-from=- --from0 /var/log/ ubuntu@ip:/`

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87018/find-and-rsync